# angularjs $compile produces ng-repeat duplicate lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am having a small issue with $compile.
I am having some html code like this:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="tutorial in tutorials" ng-click="viewTutorial(tutorial.identifier)">{{tutorial.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

This produces:

- Test
- Test2
- Test3
- Test4

Now ng-click does not work, because I am using javascript (jquery) to do

```
$('#test').html("my html with angular in it");
```

Using $compile I get ng-click to work:

```
var scope = angular.element('#test').scope();
var html = scope.compileAngular("my html with angular in it")
scope.$apply();
$('#test').html(html);
```

This will result in ng-click working, however the html looks like this:

- Test
- Test
- Test
- Test
- Test2
- Test2
- Test2
- Test2
- Test3
- Test3
- Test3
- Test3
- Test4
- Test4
- Test4
- Test4

So each item is repeated the size of the array to loop through.

I logged the html produced by $compile and it shows this:

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="tutorial in tutorials" ng-click="viewTutorial(tutorial.identifier)">{{tutorial.title}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="tutorial in tutorials" ng-click="viewTutorial(tutorial.identifier)">{{tutorial.title}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="tutorial in tutorials" ng-click="viewTutorial(tutorial.identifier)">{{tutorial.title}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="tutorial in tutorials" ng-click="viewTutorial(tutorial.identifier)">{{tutorial.title}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Does $compile already produces the final DOM? and should I filter out ng-repeat or something?

Any help on how to fix this or any tip to get ng-click to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem. Why are you using jQuery to interact with DOM in the first place?

Comment: Please post more code so we can get a better idea of this. Creating a demo would also help us help you.

Comment: @charlietfl I am using the sidr sidebar code which uses jquery to put the content in the sidebar. I am trying to adjust it to make it work with angular

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this, it was not an issue of angular's $compile rather jquery's `$(element).html()` returned multiple ng-repeat, so the wrong html.

Comment: I'm encountering the same kind of issue, but getting the inner Html using angular.element.html(), would you mind tell me how did you fixed this issue ? Thank you for pointing out that this problem wasn't directly related to angular though!

Comment: Agree with the commentor. This answer has no relevance without a solution.

Comment: You should share the solution you found.

Comment: Have you used the ng-html-compile library by any chance? https://github.com/francisbouvier/ng_html_compile

Comment: The issue I am facing is when I try ng_html_compile with a UI-Grid. Basically trying to do the following - 1) I have a HTML + AngularJS (In VisualStudio 2019) page - which I am saving to SQL Server database. 2)The page has a UI-Grid. 3)There is another form where I am displaying the saved DIVs. 4)I make use of the ng-html-compile for the DIV on the display page to show data. 5)The Grid is rendered, but I see two UI-Grids in place on one UI-Grid. 6)Why is this so and how do I fix this issue? https://gitter.im/angular-ui/ui-grid

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous response the problem was related to `$.html()` returning a wrong code. In my case that happened due to repetitive compiling the same HTML, leading to adding new replicated angular comments. To solve that I stored the resulting compiled html in a variable, and before recompiling it I used $ to remove those elements.

Basically:

```
var html = $compile($(attr.ngTarget).html())(scope); // store result
...
$(html).remove(); // clear compiled before recompiling
html = $compile($(attr.ngTarget).html())(scope);
```